# Symfony Managing Assets directly

Tags: php, symfony

Sorry for opening another topic on this but after hours of researching I haven't found a solution:

As stated in [symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) I want to include my assets (css, js, images) directly and without using Assetic. The documentation is recommending the following sniplet:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript" />
```

Unfortunately this always ends in a `404 file not found` error for every try. I have placed my assets in the `myBundle/Resources/public` folder and I also copyied it into the `web` folder using `php app/console assets:install web` without success.

What am I missing here? Is there a configuration missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, just to clarify, in `myBundle/Resources/public` there is a directory `js` which contains a file `script.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asset('js/script.js')` will produce a link like `/js/script.js`. The files will be copied to a `bundles` folder, not to the `web` root. You want something like this to generate the correct URL:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/myBundle/js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(Note also that `script` tags need to have a closing `</script>` to make them work cross-browser.)

Comment: Was easier than expected :-D Thank you.